# Invoking a parameterized method from Struts2 tag

Tags: struts2

//Action Class code:

```
public class SAStandAloneTables extends ActionSupport {

  public Object getValue(String pStr) {

    return "xyz";
  }

}
```

I am trying to call `getValue(String)` method (written in my Struts2 Action class) from the name attribute of the Struts2 textField tag in JSP file. This method accepts String as a parameter. I know how to call a method without any parameter from the Struts2 tag. But need help in this case. Please help me to write the correct OGNL expression. Sorry I couldn't post the JSP code here.

Comment: Please supply the method signature so a working example can be provided. In general: 'foo(6)' and 'bar("my_name")' are valid expressions but other expressions might be more complicated. Please consider that the actions class should marshal and digest the required information, try to have most logic there. If you find that initially disagreeable remember multiple actions can be mapped to a single action class (and different methods for execute can be supplied), that should provide adequate reuse of methods while still allowing modifications unique to a particular view.

Comment: Calling with parameters is the same as w/o parameters, only you need is to pass them. :) But yes we can't help you w/o any code from you.

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in my issue. I have added the code in my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your action by using:

```
<s:textfield name="%{getFieldName('txtName')}" value="amit Kumar" id="firstName">
</s:textfield>
```

and method like

```
public Object getFieldName(String param){
    System.out.println("here1 .");
    return param;
}
```